# Is it possible to estimate the accuracy with increasing sample size?

Tags: confidence-interval, sampling

I've just done an experiment where I sample 10% of a population and note the results of each sample.  Without much context I do KNOW that the true mean of this population parameter is 50.06%.  After 25 samples at 10% I get a list of results, a range of 1.65% and a standard deviation of 0.41%

Is it safe to assume my 95% confidence interval is therefore 0.82%?  Meaning I am 95% confident my TRUE mean of the population is within +/- 0.82%?

Without having to repeat this experiment at 20% sampling, is there a formula that can suggest how my confidence interval would improve?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you know that the true mean of the population is 50.06%, you know with 100% confidence that the population mean is within any interval that includes 50.06%. In fact, if you already know the true mean of the population there is no point in making any experiment to estimate it.

In second place, if you were actually estimating population mean, with a 0.41% standard deviation, the 95% confidence interval radius would be roughly about +/-2·0.41%/sqrt(25), that is 0.16%.

If you were to double the sample size, accuracy would be about +/-2·0.41%/sqrt(50), that is about 0.11%.

Please note that I've have done some very rough approximations, because I've assumed the value for t-Student distribution to equal 2 (both for 24 and 49 df) and because I haven't taken in account that sample size is not negligible when compared with population size. I don't think that poses a problem for the answer but it should be adjusted if sample size were to grow to became a sizeable part of population size.

Comment: Right now I know the mean is 50.06%.  This was just an experiment, in future I will NOT know this value, and need to understand is 10% sampling providing a suitable enough interval, or will doubling our effort at 20% sampling provide enough accuracy.

Comment: Then the remaining of the answer applies. Doubling sample size divides confidence interval length by square root of 2.